# Retrieving data from localStorage

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to retrieve a string from localStorage which is working, but I'm not sure of the order of execution. Or maybe I'm missing something.

```
//content_script.js

function getSize(){
    chrome.extension.sendMessage({method: "getSize"}, function(response){
        size = response.sizeIs; 
    });
    alert(size);
    return size;
}
```

and

```
//background.js

chrome.extension.onMessage.addListener(function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
    if (request.method == "getSize")
        sendResponse({sizeIs: localStorage['size']});
});
```

The alert messages are:

```
undefined
Large
```

respectively.

So I guess my question is, why is the variable working inside the sendMessage function, but not outside?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because in your example `alert(size);` executes *before* `size = response.sizeIs;`

It should be like this:

```
function getSize(callback){
  chrome.extension.sendMessage({method: "getSize"}, function(response){
    size = response.sizeIs; 
    callback(size);
  });
}
```

And call it this way:

```
getSize(function(size) {
  alert(size);
});
```

instead of:

```
size = getSize();
alert(size);
```

`chrome.extension.sendMessage` is asynchronous (non-blocking) method which means that you can't get result immediatelly. You have to pass a callback function and handle result inside

It's like `setTimeout` function. Try to execute the following code:

```
setTimeout(function() {
  console.log('test 1');
}, 100);
console.log('test 2');
```

and you will get in your console:

```
test 2
test 1
```

In the case `test 2` showed immediatelly and `test 1` - after 100ms. This is how asynchronous functions/methods work

[Here](http://recurial.com/programming/understanding-callback-functions-in-javascript/) you can read more about asynchronous functions